# Error: The submission can only contain one appx or one appxbundle

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-store

I have already published an app with the `Version 1.1.0.0`.

When I'm trying to `update` the app with a new `.appx` file after creating the `AppPackage` I'm getting this kind of an error.

It's a `Universal` app where i've published the first versions of the `Windows Store` & `Windows Phone`. Now i'm trying to update the Win Phone app where i'm facing the issue. I can't even see the replace button near the `Delete` option.

Whenever i try to upload the new appx or the bundle file, it's not letting me to submit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The issue was with the browser (Firefox) which i used!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Firefox problem - use IE and this seems to work (at least has for mine!)

Comment: Same here, firefox 34 and 35 do not work. You can update a wp8 (xap) but no universal apps. Chrome 39 does work. Thje replace button is not visible http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj631569%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try IE, Firefox doesn't show 'replace' option. Add new option is not for update. If you use replace then you will be able to update.